# Editing Bookmarks in Outlook via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following problem:
In an Excel Macro I want to open an outlook template and change various parts of this template.

My plan was to insert certain booksmarks into the template in order to edit these.

This is the Code I wrote:

```
 Sub EmailDirektSenden()

 Dim objOutlook As Object 
 Dim objRange As Range


 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("Path to the File")

 Set objRange = objMail.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range
 objRange.InsertAfter ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ReleaseCheck").Range("A5")

 End Sub
```

Unfortunately the I get the Message:

Error 438.

I would be very thankful for help.

Thanks in advance and greetings

Comment: `Dim objRange As Range`... `Range` is an `Excel.Range` here, right? That seems problematic... and then `Bookmarks` seems like a member of the `Word` object library, not `Outlook`.

Answer (score 2):

`MailItem` does not expose the `Bookmarks` property - call `MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor` - it returns an instance of the `Word.Document` object, which indeed exposes the `Bookmarks` property.